# What do we want to do with un-constructive questions that have a bounty on them?

Tags: discussion, bounties, voting-to-close

A question has been asked: [How to make a responsive theme in Zen 5? Modules and procedures to keep or to leave from older Zen versions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53818/how-to-make-a-responsive-theme-in-zen-5-modules-and-procedures-to-keep-or-to-le).

The question is not constructive and should be closed, but the OP has put a bounty on it.

It's way, way too broad and is essentially a shopping list question, neither of which are allowed as per the FAQ.

Where do we go from here? Refund the bounty and close the question? Wait for the bounty to expire and close the question? Ignoring it is not an option in my opinion as the question (while interesting) is definitely not right for Drupal Answers.

Comment: I think refund and close; that question is way too broad.  And ask OP to break it up into manageable pieces.

Comment: I think it's really an interesting question, but where else than on Drupal Answers can something like this be discussed? Is there some kind of Meta-Drupal somewhere?

Comment: @Volker The place for discussions about Drupal is [the chat room Drupal Answers has](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers). Stack Exchange sites are not for discussions, except the meta site, where you can eventually discuss the main site.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thx, never used this before. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Well the initial consensus seems to be refund & close. I'll give this a couple of hours to bed in (and give the OP a chance to respond, it looks like he's around at the moment) and we'll go from there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Refunding the bounty, and closing the question is what I would do in this case. I agree the question is not constructive, but it is also too broad. The actually asked questions are more than one, and almost all of them are equally not constructive.

Refunding the bounty, in this case is an action that is in favor of the OP, apart from being the only way to close the question. If we would wait for the bounty to be expired, the OP would lose the reputation put for the bounty. If there would be an answer with a score of two, the user who answered would get part of the bounty (if the OP doesn't accept that answer, or doesn't manually assign the bounty) for an answer that would probably completely answer the question.

Refunding a bounty is not a punishment for the OP, in the same way closing a question is not punishing who asked the question, or answered it.

Comment: Exactly, this one comes to mind when i read the question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I have read the questions a few times, and don't really get what the question is.

There is too much background / extraneous information.  The post really needs to be edited down to essentials.  For example this seems to be really irrelevant to the actual question:

> Compass, SASS, the use of a Ruby CSS preprocessor (compass) running as
>   a server to generate CSS files from SASS, and not to improve loading
>   times by the client are some of the new design concepts implemented
>   through Zen Grids. Respond.js and HTML5 shim seems to be new
>   retrocompatibility concepts. Zen Grids seems to be able to do most of
>   the work Panels and templates used to do.

Once it is edited down, hopefully some focus can be given to it, and it can be salvaged.

Comment: As an aside, I would use this as an opportunity to re-evaluate your base theme of choice.  It is possible that other base themes may fit your needs better.  We did this about a year ago, and jumped from Zen to Omega. and gave ourselves a fresh start.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Omega. I've also started playing with Twitter Bootstrap recently and like it too (Despite its requiring jQuery Update). Apologies for the off-topicness!

Answer (score 0):

The question is about how to approach the complexity of Zen 5 themes. If it's confused or broad it's because the question itself is about complexity and broadness of methods required by Zen 5 in contrast of Zen.

Splitting it in small pieces (bottom to top approach) is what actually I and my team are trying to do, but the right answer for this question should address the problem about the working method to adopt while making large website, what to avoid and what to use of the older Zen methods / module we used till 2007. The goal is to guide developers that worked with older Zen themes. I agree to close the question if not constructive, but I appreciate suggestions  about constructive questions that could be more manageable than this one.

Note: 20 days are passed from the first writing of the question and in the meanwhile it wasn't closed as not constructive, indicating or it was unnoticed or that the second writing is worst than the first one.

Comment: The question simply passed unobserved (which is the reason you put a bounty `;)`). It is the bounty that made the question more evident, not the second revision that was worse than the first one.